# MSTest - Can [DataRow] values be accessed in TestInitialize and TestCleanup?

Tags: c#, mstest, data-driven-tests

I'm having tests like so:

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow("example1")]
[DataRow("example2")]
public void Test_Example(string name)
{
  // test logic
}
```

Our logging system is currently implemented in a single `[TestCleanup]` method in a base `[TestClass]`.

I can access the test method's name via the `TestContext` property, but that does not include any info regarding the datarow parameters.

Is it possible to get these values somehow? In `[TestCleanup]` or in `[TestInitialize]` would do fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the DataRow property on the TestContext object? This might be what you're after.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.datarow?view=mstest-net-1.2.0

Comment: Nope, that only has data when using [DataSource] rather than [DataRow]. That's what we used before.